# Finding parentheses in python regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have text strings that look like this:

`yryr%(DENHP@Germany)`

I want my output to look like this:

`yryr__DENHP_Germany_`

(I'd also like to replace periods and commas).

These are actually variables in a pandas dataframe, and I'm trying to match parentheses at the minute... here's what I'm trying but it isn't quite working. Could someone please help?

`df_q_raw.columns = df_q_raw.columns.str.replace(['\.\%r'\('r'\)'], '')`

Comment: Are you just replacing all non-alphanumeric characters with `_`? If so just use `\W` replace with `_`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To only remove parentheses, percentage sign, periods and commas, you may use

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(r'[()%.,]', '_')
```

To replace any non-word char, may use

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(r'\W', '_')
```

The `\W` pattern matches any non-word char. If you do not want to match a whitespace, use `[^\w\s]`.

If you also want to replace `_` (also considered a word char), you need to use `[\W_]` instead, or, if you do not want to match a whitespace, use `(?!\s)[\W_]`.

Comment: I just want to replace them in the dataframe column names, nowhere else.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Specifically used your `\W` method to replace all non-alphanumeric values.

Answer (score 0):

`str.replace` does not work with regexes. You should use `re.sub` instead.

Judging from your examples, you want to replace `(`, `)`, `.`, `%` and `@` with `_`:

```
re.sub(r"[().%@]", '', df_q_raw.columns.str)
```

`[]` denotes a character class. A character will be matched if it is a member of the character class.

If you want to replace all non-alphanumeric characters, use this regex instead: `\W`